# How do I get Bookshelf.js to return all rows including rows with duplicate data

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using `Bookshelf.js` and `Knex.js` to query my database for data, however it seems that the **ORM** is not returning all rows that match my query. My query is written below.

```
MyModel.where({id: req.params.id})
.fetchAll({withRelated: ['children.children']})
.then(result => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify({myData: result}));
});
```

This is returning some data that I need but leaving out rows that while containing the same data in each column, have a different unique ID. So, they are different entries that simply contain the same data. I need this function to return all rows and not filter out any rows that have the same data in them.

Now I understand that it would be preferred to avoid duplicate data but I need all of it for my specific use case. Is there a way that `Bookshelf.js` or `Knex.js` could return all rows and not filter out what it "thinks" is duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Knex / bookshelf does not filter out any data that "it thinks" being duplicate. If you are querying all rows where `id = req.params.id` knex will return all the rows that has requested `id`.

Try to run the code with `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable to see the query that bookshelf sends to DB. If query seems to be wrong please add it to question. If just results seems to be wrong check DB contents and add that information to the question.